# how to suppress "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar" message

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and Java 1.7. After updating to 15.04, whenever I type any Java command, I get a message like:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

For example:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

How can I suppress this behavior?

Comment: There is no way to suppress the output https://community.oracle.com/thread/1239778

Comment: Please don't use code snippets unless it's HTMl/CSS/Javascript.

Comment: In the discussion https://community.oracle.com/thread/1239778 it has mentioned about some java.bat, can this help? Can we have equivalent of this for Ubuntu please

Comment: What does `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= java -version` prints out?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_21"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 and had the same problem (though, I didn't feel it as a problem).

```
$ echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
$ apt-cache search jayatana
jayatana - Java Native Library for ayatana project
```

From this output I can conclude, that something `ayatana` is trying to attach its agent to all started Java code.

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana) says, that

> Ayatana is a collective effort to improve the user experience of software in and for Ubuntu.

So, it looks like this application is attaching agent to ensure application to be stable or something like this.

The easy way of eliminating this variable is just unsetting it in `~/.profile`:

```
$ echo unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS >>~/.profile
```

But this looks more like workaround and if you're sure you don't need this application, you can fully remove it:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove jayatana
```

Comment: I have removed it once but then getting error for command like "jps". So re-install it back again. The work around you provided didn't work for me.

Comment: @KoushikChandra this workaround should work only after restarting console or something like `source ~/.profile`. Did you do this?

Comment: What I mean here after this echo JAVA_TOOL_OPTION step; I am not getting "-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar", but getting "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTION:" in standard output. Can the message "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTION:" be totally suppressed?

Comment: I have restarted console as you have said. Before applying this change the message which I am getting is "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar" and after applying this change I am getting "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:". What I mean the message is not totally going.

Comment: @KoushikChandra could you please paste output of `cat ~/.profile && env` (in new console) into some paste service and send here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77869/discussion-between-koushik-chandra-and-dmitry-ginzburg).

Comment: Could you please any of your email as the output is too huge to paste here

Comment: the output for "cat ~/.profile && env" can be found in the link pastebin.com/561mqea9

Comment: @KoushikChandra looks live you've not applied what I've wrote in the last update of the post. You should have only one record, either in `.profile` or in `.bashrc`, not both. You may edit one file to remove `JAVA_TOOL_OPTION=` line and the other to replace it with `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`

Comment: Ginzburz -- I am sorry, I missed that unset option previously. Thanks for reminding again.

Comment: Just an information: Jayatana makes Java applications integrate better with Ubuntu's Unity (like making the global/local menu and HUD work in Java).

Answer (score 3):

There is a complete answer by Ron over on askubuntu and i quote

> **Option 1: Remove jayatana package**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove jayatana
> ```
>
> If you do not need global menu support for Java swing applications,
>   you can simply remove the package. Removing the package will not cause
>   more harm than making menus of java swing based applications such as
>   eclipse and intellij move back inside the window of the application.
>
> **Option 2: Remove only the annoying message**
>
> ```
> sudo rm /usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf
> ```
>
> This will remove the auto-start configuration of Jayatana and you
>   won't see the annoying message ever. Again, this will disable the
>   global menu support of Java Swing applications.

The entire solution is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650548/remove-annoying-environment-variable-java-tool-options/650597#650597)